# Calculating posterior of exponential distribution and finding 80% credible interval

Tags: self-study, bayesian

My homework problem is: Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be random samples from an $Exp(\lambda)$ distribution. Assume that the prior on $\lambda$ is $\Gamma(a,b)$.

a) Find the posterior distribution for $\lambda$.
Prior: $\frac{b^a}{\Gamma(a)}\lambda^{a-1}e^{-b\lambda}$
Likelihood: $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$

$\pi(\lambda|x)\propto \pi(x|\lambda)\pi(\lambda) \propto \Pi_{i=1}^n(\lambda e^{-\lambda x_i})\lambda^{a-1}e^{-b\lambda}\propto \lambda^{a+n-1}e^{-\lambda(b+s)}$ where $s=x_1+...+x_n$. This can be represented by $\Gamma(a+n,b+s)$.

This part I looked over my lecture notes along with a bunch of online sources, but can't figure out if it's right.

b) Assume $n=10,a=5,b=3,\mu=15$. Find an 80%-credible set for $\lambda$.

I know the setup would be $\int_l^u \Gamma(a+n,b+s) = 0.8$ and I would have to figure out the inverse gamma function, but it doesn't make sense with the gamma that I got for part a.

I used an online calculator to find $C(1575.84,3079.59)$. Any confirmation on this interval would be great.

Comment: When the posterior is known, one way of constructing an 80% credible interval for the parameter is to choose symmetric quantiles of the distribution, so the 10th and the 90th percentiles of the Gamma posterior.

Comment: @AdamO I understood that part. What I'm stuck on is if my posterior is even correct, because right now I'm getting values that don't make sense

Comment: 1. Check your calculations in relation to $b$ in the posterior. 2. Also, is the online calculator using the same parameterization of the gamma that you're dealing with in the question? There are several common parameterizations (shape-rate, shape-scale, shape-mean, ...). My advice would be to avoid online calculators in general and instead use something whose parameterizations are completely explicit and which will tend to offer the ability to use more than one parameterization. R comes to mind but it's far from the only possibility. 3.

Comment: In terms of (b), it's not clear to me where $\mu=15$ comes from, since you seem to be using the shape-rate parameterization in your calculation.

Comment: @Glen_b The calculator allowed me to enter data for $a$ and $b$ along with the probability that I wanted to find. I'm not familiar with R, so it doesn't seem worth it to me to learn for this one problem. But I checked one of their other calculators using a known problem and it worked.

Comment: Sure, but the question is whether what *it* calls $b$ is the same as what *you* call $b$. Indeed I also wonder in my second comment above whether what you call $b$ matches what the author of the question calls $b$. Take a look at the two parameterizations of the gamma distribution on wikipedia and consider what happens if someone calls $k,\theta$ there $a,b$ while you're calling $\alpha, \beta$ $a$ and $b$ respectively

Comment: @Glen_b $\mu=15$ is a given parameter along with the other parameters for part b. I was able to show $\Gamma(5+10, 3+(10*15))=\Gamma(15,153)$.

Comment: I really think you need to very carefully look at how you did that. Please look at the wikipedia page I mention above, closely, and ponder what happens if you are not using the same parameterization as the question's author. In particular, your $b$ is NOT a scale parameter. The mean of the prior you wrote in your question is not $ab$ but $a/b$.

Comment: I plan to go to office hours on Thursday to see if the TA can help me understand it more. I've spent a few hours researching this one problem and still don't know if I'm going in the right direction.